# Read lines between two markers

Tags: python, parsing, readfile

How can I read a text file one section at a time between two markers.
for example;

```
**<Start>** 
code:2010
<Stop>
<Start>
code:2011
code:2013
**<Stop>**
```

and have it print out one line at a time:

```
*code:2010
code:2011
code:2013*
```

I'm using Python3. I've tried looking at 're' but I think I'm way off base. I'm also on a windows machine and don't believe awk or sed are available to me.
Any direction would be welcome. Thank you!

Comment: I think you're over thinking this.  If all the data and markers are on separate lines, just read each line one at a time straight from the file and check the contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work for your example, but I honestly haven't tested it:

```
start = 0
textlist = []
with open('myfile') as f:
    for line in f:
        if '<STOP>' in line.upper():
            start = 0
        elif start:
            textlist.append(line)
        elif '<START>' in line.upper():
            start = 1
print(''.join(textlist))
```

Comment: That's what I needed. Thank you Kind Stranger!

Answer (score 0):

If it's a text/csv you could do something like the following:

```
import csv
codes = []
with open('myfile.csv', newline='') as f:
     reader=csv.reader(f)
     for line in reader:
           if "code:" in line:
                codes.append([line])


with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
     writer = csv.writer(f)
     writer.writerows(codes)
```